# Any peer reviewed scientific study on the effects of vacuum penis pumps on penis girth?

Tags: penis

I can't find any study either proving it works or it doesn't. It's probably my google-fu that is lacking but can anyone link to a study about using the penis pumps to increase penis girth?

I am aware that the only proven methods to increase length is PTT devices, but my concern is girth only